# IntelliJ missing resources folder in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

My Maven project in IntelliJ Idea have no resources folder both in main and test folder. I know how to manually create those folders and update pom accordingly, but how can I do it automatically in IntelliJ Idea? In Eclipse there is an option like "Update project".

Answer (score 0):

First you want to right click on your project and choose "Add Framework Support" to allow Intellij to recognize that this is a Maven project. Assuming that you have your pom.xml ready, right click on it, hover over on "Maven" choose "Reimport" and/or "Generate Sources and Update Folders"

Comment: First of all intellij is recognizing this project as Maven one. Secondly "Reimport" and/or "Generate Sources and Update Folders" does not create resources folder under src/main and src/test